# Gettiing Cython up and running on OS X

Tags: python, macos, cython

I seem to have made an error installing Cython on OS X, though I didn't get an error during installation. What I did was

- download cython and move the tarball to my home folder
- unpack the tarball and run `python setup.py install`

Everything seemed to work, i.e. I got no errors.

However, this doesn't work work when I try it in python:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport rand, RAND_MAX
```

In particular I can see that neither `import libc.stdlib` nor `cimport` work on their own.

What I'm trying to do is use the C random number generator following [this tutorial](http://hplgit.github.io/teamods/MC_cython/sphinx/main_MC_cython.html). I have a feeling I'm just leaving out something very obvious that may have more to do with the general install of a python module and less to do with Cython itself.

Comment: Are you compiling the cython file or are you just running that import command in Python? Try taking a look at [the docs on compilation](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html). The tutorial you linked to has a brief explanation at the bottom as well.

Comment: First, why not just `pip install cython`? (If you haven't [installed `pip` yet](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html), do that.)

Answer (score 1):

> However, this doesn't work work when I try it in python:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport rand, RAND_MAX
```

> In particular I can see that neither `import libc.stdlib` nor `cimport` work on their own.

That's because they don't work in Python code, they only work in Cython code.

The [Cython Basic Tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html) shows you a few different ways to create programs or extensions in Cython and build them (including `pyximport`, which does the building implicitly if needed at runtime).

The tutorial you're following *also* covers this, in [the first section that mentions Cython](http://hplgit.github.io/teamods/MC_cython/sphinx/main_MC_cython.html#migrating-scalar-python-code-to-cython). It shows you how to put this code into a separate file with extension `.pyx`, and to build and run a simple `setup.py` to build it, and then `import` the build module from a `.py` script.